# How do I loop through each substring in a string and do stuff at that substring's location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want to loop through each substring in a string and do stuff at that substring's location, but after a lot of googling I can't figure out how to do it.

Basically, I have a variable containing a string with HTML code that will be appended to a div. The string contains HTML code for a number of input fields. I want to find each occurence of the substring `name="`, then search for the next occurence of a quotation mark (i e the end of the variable name, which can be different every time), and insert two square brackets [] before the quotation mark. The point of this is to convert the HTML input variable to an array in this case.

I'm imagining something like this (pseudo code warning):

```
function changeNameVariableIntoArrayVariable(htmlString) {
    var subString = "name=\"";
    var insertString = "[]";
    foreach (subString in htmlString) {
        find the next quotation mark (\") closest to the right of subString;
        htmlString.insert(insertString to the left of quotationmark);
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```

Can this be done/is this a good idea? Thanks.

EDIT: From a request in the comments, here's an example of what might be the input htmlString and what the expected output should be:

Input:

```
<div class="select-new-container">
<label>Name:<br>
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="artist">
</label><br>
<label>Lifespan:<br>
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="artistlife">
</label><br>
<label>Instrument:<br>
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="artistrole">
</label><br>
</div>
```

Expected output:

```
<div class="select-new-container">
<label>Name:<br>
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="artist[]">
</label><br>
<label>Lifespan:<br>
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="artistlife[]">
</label><br>
<label>Instrument:<br>
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="artistrole[]">
</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be better if you provide a sample string and its resulting output.

Comment: What would you need that for? Why not use DOM properties, and access names through that?

Comment: I tried doing that and using jQuery each(), but it wouldn't allow that with a string that's not yet been attached to the document.

Comment: @Dij see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bad idea](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) to parse HTML with regular expressions. But a simple search & replace shouldn't hurt too much.

```
htmlString.replace(/(name="[^"]+)(")/g, '$1[]$2');
```

But in general, this looks like a "do my homework for me" question, so it might be more helpful to actually learn about the basic elements of JavaScript like regular expressions.

Comment: Could you make an ELI5/idiot version of what each of all those signs after name=" are doing? I understand /g but that's about it. Also what do you mean by parsing and regular expressions? Sorry, I'm very new to coding.

Comment: @coding_pianist - Take a look at [Explain Regular Expressions](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%28name%3D%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%28%22%29%2Fg).

Comment: @coding_pianist: No, I couldn't, because it doesn't really get easier than typing "regular expressions" into Google and reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @hon2a I think I might be dumb because I'm finding it hella confusing to understand the explanations :P I shall read it through a couple of times and see if I get anywhere... Thanks!

Comment: @coding_pianist: Np. Here's [another intro](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html) that might be more digestible than raw docs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you've asked for, but if it was real non-string HTML then you could simply access the name attribute through `getAttribute` DOM object method.

HTML:

```
<input name="hello" />
```

JS:

```
 // access the value in name attribute
 var nameAttrVal = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("name");

 // manipulate it
 nameAttrVal = nameAttrVal + "[]"; 

 console.log(nameAttrVal); // prints "hello[]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm basically constructing forms dynamically by using various functions to create and combine different types of input fields with different variable names. The function I'm trying to create is supposed to make certain of the input variables into arrays before appending the entire html string to the form div. I might have to find out which stuff in the form is supposed to have array variables and convert them with your method after the fact. My only objection to that is that it seems like the code will be more "spread out" in different places, so to speak.